# ls strange behavior when i give it `-- ` as argument

Tags: linux, unix

When I execute `ls --`:

```
$ls --
a.out       ft_ls.c     ft_ls.h     ft_ls.h.gch libft`
```

it display the content of the current directory, 
but the `-` alone is interpreted like a directory named '-':

```
$ls -
ls: -: No such file or directory
```

and `ls ---` is illegal flag:

```
$ls ---
ls: illegal option -- -
usage: ls [-ABCFGHLOPRSTUWabcdefghiklmnopqrstuwx1] [file ...]
```

and can I know why `---` isn't interpreted by default as a file name?

Comment: You'll find that many programs recognize `--` as an option marking the end of the option list, so that any subsequent arguments are treated as non-options, even if they start with `-`.  Beyond that, it's unclear what you're asking.

Comment: @pmg i am trying to implement ls using C. but i forgot that is a wrong flag for the question, thanks.

Comment: For some programs, they support the _convention_ that `--` separates options from arguments [and gets silently absorbed], so `ls --` is just like `ls`. Try: `ls -- -l` for example

Comment: I removed the C tag. You may like to read [POSIX Utility Syntax Guidelines](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html#tag_12_02)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`--` has a special meaning as the marker of "end of options"; whereas `---` or `-` has no such special meaning.

[POSIX](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap12.html) convention says:

> The first -- argument that is not an option-argument should be
>   accepted as a delimiter indicating the end of options. Any following
>   arguments should be treated as operands, even if they begin with the
>   '-' character.

If you are implementing `ls` then you might be interested in using [`getopt`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html) function and you can easily implement similar option processing as the `ls` command.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few instances when you have to run `ls --` command.

Here is one, if you have any file that start with a dash (`-`) for example `-file.pdf` ; using ls with any option will cause errors. You will need to use ls with double dash `ls --` which tells Linux to ignore everything else after that has a dash and then type the file name with a *.

You can use `ls -- *.pdf` to display your directory contents.